# Regex match with next being either a space or end of string

Tags: php, regex

My regfu has declined... and I'm having trouble getting expected matches.

Here's example of what needs to match and what not:

- NLNL **LL**
- LNLN **LL LL**
- NNLL **LL LL LL**
- LNLN LLL **LL**
- LLNN LL LLL <-- skip because:

Only need:

- 1 to 3 Pairs of letters separated by one space
- Which are consecutive to end of string

`\s{1}([A-Z]{2})` is close, but also grabbing part of the skip above.

Why? I need to grab what are name initials from strings. There are either 1,2,or 3 persons initials appended to the strings. I will be grabbing those with PHP to store them.

Comment: Try `(?:\s[A-Z]{2})+$`, or if you are sure there will be only 1, 2 or 3 of them and you need to get them all, you may use `\s([A-Z]{2})(?:\s([A-Z]{2}))?(?:\s([A-Z]{2}))?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hEjXhv/2))

Comment: Or, a bit more sophisticated: `(?:\G(?!\A)|(?=(?:\s[A-Z]{2})+$))\s\K[A-Z]{2}`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wy04vN/1)

Comment: It's not really clear, why exactly the last one should be skipped? It's in the end of the string and it's 3 letters (matching `1 to 3 letters`).

Comment: @TheGodfather  - 1 to 3 PAIRS of letters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Indeed. Was right on. Upvoted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
if (preg_match('~(?: [A-Z]{2})+$~', $s, $match)) {
    print_r(explode(" ", trim($match[0])));
}
```

Here, `(?: [A-Z]{2})+$` matches one or more sequences of a space and then two uppercase ASCII letters till the end of string, and then `explode(" ", trim($match[0]))` splits the trimmed match with a space into chunks.

Or, if you want to match all occurrences with one regex call:

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|(?=(?:\s[A-Z]{2})+$))\s\K[A-Z]{2}~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Here, the regex matches:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|(?=(?:\s[A-Z]{2})+$))` - end of previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) a location immediately followed with one or more sequences of a space and then two uppercase ASCII letters till the end of string
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase ASCII letters.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/aTo3V).